# Putting CGI script in HTML page

Tags: html, shell, cgi

I don't know much about web programming and I would really appreciate the help on this.

I have an HTML page that has an input field:

```
<input type="text" size=20 />
```

I want to run a CGI script that will return a value so that I can put it in the input field as a default when the page first loads.

So it would look like this I guess:

```
<input type="text" size=20 value=Run CGI script />
```

The script is a shell script that I named hostname.cgi and it contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
printf $REMOTE_ADDR
```

When I try using

```
value=<!--include virtual="hostname.cgi" -->
```

I get an error on the HTML page that says an error occurred while running this directive (or something like that).

What am I doing wrong?  Also, the script is in the same directory as the html file. Other CGI scripts on the page work just fine.

Comment: If it says an error occurred when running the SSI, look in your server error logs to find out what the error was.

Comment: Sounds like you need some [AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257110/ajax-tutorial#257116)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do here, I would really have to see the whole code. However, I suspect it's somethign to do with your format and the action defined:

```
<form action="/some_script_name" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ab" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You also need to surround attributes with quotes:

```
<input type="text" size="20" value="Run CGI script" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To put some default value somewhere as generated by a CGI script, you need to make the entire page generated by a CGI script. This means that the address of the page would be a reference to such a script. The details depend on the programming language used for the CGI script.